# Breaking down a public IP into components

Tags: php

I am programming in PHP and I want to be able to break down a value such as `46.222.15.198` into distinct parts such as `46`, `222`, `15` and `198`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go very simple and use [explode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php):

```
$ipParts = explode('.', '46.222.15.198');
```

This returns an array with 4 elements, with keys from 0 to 3.

> Explode: Returns an array of strings, each of which is a substring of string formed by splitting it on boundaries formed by the string delimiter.
>
> explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit = PHP_INT_MAX ] )
>   parameters:
>
> - delimiter: The boundary string.
> - string: The input string.
> - limit If limit is set and positive, the returned array will contain a
>     maximum of limit elements with the last element containing the rest of
>     string.
>
>   If the limit parameter is negative, all components except the last 
>     limit are returned.
>
>   If the limit parameter is zero, then this is treated as 1.

Alternatively you can assign each part to a specific variable like this:

```
list($w, $x, $y, $z) = explode('.', '46.222.15.198');
```

Answer (score 0):

Explode the string.

```
$parts = explode('.', $ip);
```